# Multi product transport problem on opensourse libraries

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming

I've found nice solution (https://scipbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#multi-product-transportation-problem) for multiproduct model on gurobi python. But it is not opensourse product. Is there any nice solution for multiproduct problem on opesourse products like pulp? 
And how to formulate a problem in python with it?

Comment: This is not a complex model and transcribing the stated mathematical model into Pulp should be quite straightforward.

Comment: Oh, thx. I made an elephant out of a fly...